# Problem with escaping double quote Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I start building a Jenkins job with a Jenkinsfile. In one of my steps, I create a variable. This variable echo's as expected, now I try to insert this variable into a new function and need to escape, everything looked fine until I see the last double quote on a new line and not on the end.

The line of code that create my variable is:

```
gitTag = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "git describe --tags--always")
```

The line code that use this variable:

```
sh "echo WEBSERVICE_VERSION=\"$gitTag\" > ${WORKSPACE}/webservice/src/webservice_version.py"
```

expected output `WEBSERVICE_VERSION="$gitTag"`, but the output I see is `WEBSERVICE_VERSION=$gitTag`.

Did I make any mistake in escaping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you

```
node('master'){
def gitTag="mytag"
sh "touch webservice_version.py"
sh "echo \\\"${gitTag}\\\"  > webservice_version.py"
sh "cat webservice_version.py"
}
```